# Cypress error "The automation client disconnected. Cannot continue running tests." when running in Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I'm getting the following error when running a Cypress test suite in a Docker container:

> The automation client disconnected. Cannot continue running tests.

Using this command, running in a `cypress/browsers:node12.6.0-chrome75` container:

`cypress run --browser=chrome`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to occur when running out of shm space.

By default, Docker creates a container with a `/dev/shm` shared memory space of 64MB.
This is typically too small for Chrome and could cause Chrome to crash.

I have found two options to resolve this:

1. Disable usage of `/dev/shm`:

```
// cypress/plugins/index.js

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // ref: https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Usage
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      args.push('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
      return args
    }

    return args
  })
}
```

2. Increase the size of `/dev/shm` in the container:

Run the container with `docker run --shm-size=1gb` (or whatever size you want)

Comment: Option 2 seems to be really helpful if you know you've got a lot of RAM or a really large test suite (which you should break down, but you need to get it running [headless] in CI before you can break it down).